# Using ts-loader with strip-loader in Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to use strip-loader in a Typescript project built with Webpack, but not having any luck.

My ts-loader statement looks like:

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015!ts-loader' }
```

...and this works fine. Typescript targets ES6 and I end up with ES5 thanks to Babel. But my code has lots of console logging using Angular's $log service, so I want to strip out lines looking like:

```
this.$log.log ("Some message here");
```

So I updated my Webpack file with:

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015!strip-loader?strip[]=this.log!ts-loader' }
```

So thinking "right to left", TS generates ES6, strip-loader takes out any line beginning `this.$log` and Babel takes the result and produces ES5.

But no-joy. No matter what pattern I pass to strip-loader (i.e. `strip[]=this`), it doesn't touch the code.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You have `$` in your pattern which means end of string in regex. Thy to escape it:

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015!strip-loader?strip[]=this.\\$log.log!ts-loader' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no joy.

Comment: @jeffeld I had missed to escape the escape sign in the string. Edited.